Downloading OneDrive Files with Powershell and Graph Get-MgDriveItemContent
I'm trying to download OneDrive Files with the Graph module. But I get an error at the last step. I'm out of ideas on how to proceed. Anyone have a clue for me?

    Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All"
#
# Import users from CSV
$terminatedUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Desktop\OneDriveUsersBackup.csv"

foreach ($user in $terminatedUsers) {
    $userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    
    # Create a directory for the user's data
    $userDirectory = "C:\TerminatedUsers\$userPrincipalName"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $userDirectory -Force

    # Fetch user information
    $userObject = Get-MgUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"

    # Fetch user's OneDrive drives
    $userOneDrive = Get-MgUserDefaultDrive -UserId $userObject.id


        $driveId = $userOneDrive.id
        #Get-MgUserDriveItemContent -UserId $userObject.id -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId "root" -OutFile $userDirectory
        Get-MgDriveItemContent -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId "root" -OutFile $userDirectory
    
}


You are trying to download the whole root folder? I think that downloading folder it's not supported.

Yes, I am attempting to download the whole folder. Maybe I should enumerate each object in the folder, drop them into an array, and try downloading them like that.

Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code by passing "root" as value for -DriveItemId in Get-MgDriveItemContent command:
Get-MgDriveItemContent -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId "root" -OutFile $userDirectory

Response:


The error occurred as you are trying to fetch content directly from the root of the drive without specifying a valid DriveItemId.

I have one user account named Sri having below files in One Drive account:

To download these OneDrive Files with Microsoft Graph PowerShell, you can make use of below modified script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.ReadWrite.All", "Sites.ReadWrite.All", "Files.ReadWrite.All"

# Import users from CSV
$terminatedUsers = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\me\Desktop\OneDriveUsersBackup.csv"

foreach ($user in $terminatedUsers) {
    $userPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    
    # Create a directory for the user's data
    $userDirectory = "C:\TerminatedUsers\$userPrincipalName"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $userDirectory -Force

    # Fetch user information
    $userObject = Get-MgUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"

    # Fetch user's OneDrive drives
    $userOneDrive = Get-MgUserDefaultDrive -UserId $userObject.id
    $driveId = $userOneDrive.id

    # Fetch root drive item
    $rootDriveItem = Get-MgDriveItem -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId "root"

    # Fetch children of the root drive item
    $driveItemChildren = Get-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $rootDriveItem.id

    # Loop through each drive item
    foreach ($item in $driveItemChildren) {
        # Check if the item is a file based on MIME type
        if ($item.File.MimeType -ne $null) {
            $fileDirectory = $userDirectory
            $fileName = $item.name

            # Download the file
            Get-MgDriveItemContent -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $item.id -OutFile (Join-Path -Path $fileDirectory -ChildPath $fileName)
        } else {
            # If it's not a file, it could be a folder, we can skip it
            continue
        }
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the path where OneDrive files downloaded successfully as below:

In the case of downloading folders, you should enumerate each object in the folder, drop them into an array, and try downloading them like that as you mentioned in comments.
